# What is the correct way to get and manipulate more input fields with same class-name

Tags: jquery, input

I want to manipulate user input fields.
Is this the right way? Or any idea to minimize?

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGLH2/2/)

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control value_no" id="01" type="text" value="0" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control value_no" id="02" type="text" value="0" />
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#01").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var result = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
    $('#01').val(result);
    }).keyup();

    $("#02").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var result = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
    $('#02').val(result);
    }).keyup();
})
```

Comment: A little more info on what type(s) of manipulation you want to perform would be helpful. Is restriction to numeric values all you are looking to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the common class and an instance of `this` to avoid repeating similar code:

```
$(".value_no").keyup(function () {
    var value = this.value
    var result = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
    this.value = result;
}).keyup();
```

Also, use `this.value`, not `$(this).val()` -- no need to get jQuery happy :)

Answer (score 0):

You're repeating too much code (as I suspect you are aware of).

Use a selector that finds both the inputs instead. From the code you've posted "input.value_no" should be a good selector, but without having the entire html code available it's impossible to say if it will match any more controls by accident:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.value_no").keyup(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var result = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
        $(this).val(result);
    }).keyup();
})
```